# After a restore, how can I tell when the database backup was generated

Tags: postgresql

I have a server with a DB that was restored from production. I have the dumpfile which has a date stamp but this could have changed. On the server with the restored DB, is it possible to find out what date the dumpfile was created.

I am using the restored server to prepare historic reports and wish to be able to put in the report title database generated at DATE.

I looked at man pages hoping to find reference to a log file but didn't.

Comment: No. There is no "magic timestamp" hidden anywhere. If you don't have a table with timestamps that gets regularly updated you could always add one and update it once an hour.